# Troubles to show like counts in WP theme

Tags: facebook-graph-api, wordpress-theming, facebook-page

I'm theming my Wordpress and want to show just number of likes in a fan page. How can I show this

> https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id=160397290640478

in my theme? I can't use fopen() function. Maybe javascript? How?

Sorry for this question, but I'm not a programmer.

---

Sorry, but after all, I got my own answer:

http://pastebin.com/desK1b6D

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, when pastebin doesn't work anymore, here's the solution to the problem:

```
<script>
    function showCount(count){
        if(count)
        document.getElementById('fb_fan_count').innerHTML = count[0].fan_count;
    }
</script>
<p id="fb_fan_count"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&callback=showCount&query=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D16039729064048"></script>
```